# Eliminar fila de datagrid con entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Quisiera eliminar una fila del datagrid al momento de presionar un botón de "Eliminar"

Tengo esto:

```
private void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Id != "")
            {
                XXXXX Item = new XXXXX();
                using (var context = new PruebaEnti())
                {
                    Item = context.xxxxx.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
                    
                    context.SaveChanges();
                   
                }
            }

        }
```

Me salta este error:

> Additional information: No se puede eliminar filas mediante
> programación a menos que DataGridView esté enlazado a datos con
> IBindingList que admita la notificación de cambios y permita la
> eliminación.

Comment: Si tienes tu `DataGridView` enlazado a datos, para eliminar una fila, lo que debes hacer es eliminar el registro correspondiente en la tabla enlazada y actualizar el  `DataGridView`, la fila se aliminará automaticamente; si lo enlazas con `IBindingList` cuando intentes eliminar una fila, notificará a la base de datos y se aliminará el registro asociado a la fila.

Comment: Hola, podrías decirme si la respuesta dada te fue util

Comment: agradecería también tu voto, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes tener en cuenta que para que se vean los datos en tu **DataGridView** debes tener una fuente de datos enlazada a este, por lo que deberías poner en el **evento Load** de tu formulario:

```
dg.DataSource = context.xxx.ToList();
```

De esta forma aparece el **DataGridView** cargado.

Ahora bien para eliminar un elemento debes hacer esto:

```
context.xxx.Remove(Item);
context.SaveChanges();
```

De esta forma eliminas el objeto de la base de datos, ahora lo que vendría sería actualizar el **DataGridView** ya que la información cambió, por tanto debes volver a cargar la fuente de datos:

```
dg.DataSource = context.xxx.ToList();
```

Y se mostrará en el **DataGridView** la información actualizada.